# Convert html and svg to pdf

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, svg, makepdf

I am creating a project using angularjs. I have problem while converting html and svg to pdf. I am using the plugins:

Simple html is converted to pdf, but svg is not converting into pdf.

Here is my sample code which works only for html:

```
 var html = document.getElementById('container_div');
html2canvas(html, {
                  useCORS: true,
                  allowTaint: true,
                  letterRendering: true,
                  onrendered: function (canvas) {
                  var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                  var docDefinition = {
                      content: [{
                          image: data,
                          width: 510,
                      }]
                  };
                  pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('price-calculation-' + $scope.getDateTimeFormat("YYYY-MM-DD-hh:mm:ss") + '.pdf');
                  $("#price-pdf-content").hide()
                  $('#export-pricing-model').modal('hide');

              }
          });
```

Here is html:

```
<div class="row" id="container_div">
here are some divs which is converted to pdf
-------
----------
<svg id="svg_0" width="262" height="33" style="z-index:201;position:absolute;left:209px;top:89px" source-endpoint="b0668836-0ffb-ac83-fed3-e6c0e7b708df" destination-endpoint="83669f6e-6d12-aa90-717d-1c5e1a509809"><line id="line_0" class="line" x1="252" y1="23" x2="10" y2="10" stroke="#99ca3c" stroke-width="3" linkuuid="2c03ba9a-4dbe-e4b9-51ac-8a4038012189"></line></svg>// this svg is not converted

</div>
```

Comment: html2canvas, probably an issue with SVG conversion to canvas (pixels) ?

Comment: yes..............

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Caged/4649511, I have not tried this but you could have a look.